# Changing img src does not display image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit: Okay, the code is fine. There was some other code that was supposed to set other attributes somewhere else and I fell prey to the "copy/paste forgot to change the ID name" disease. Thanks for everyone's input. Sorry for being a bonehead.

I have a situation where I am using jquery to dynamically change the img src attribute when the user click an image. Basically switching back and forth between a Register and an UnRegister button. When I click on the register button it correctly switches to the UnRegister image. However, it will never switch back to the Register image if I click on it again. My code:

```
function unRegister() { 
        $('#reg').attr("src","/images/btnRegister.png");             
        $('#reg').attr("onClick","register()");
}
function register() {
        $('#reg').attr("src","/images/btnUnregister.png");              
        $('#reg').attr("onClick","unRegister()");          
}
```

Seems easy enough. I've verified that both images are spelled correctly and are in the /images directory. I need the two routines because once this little problem is solved I will be doing many different things based on what operation is happening. I've verified (via the handy alert() call that the routines are being called, just no image switch.

Comment: Hi, can you link the images live ?  Is http://yoursite/images/btnRegister.png 404 ??  also confirm $(#reg) is just a typo mistake and not YOUR ERROR.

Comment: Can you confirm that your code is `$('#reg')` and not $(#reg)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kvagn/ Your code looks good actually. Switches images properly.

Comment: Yes it works after you have added missing apostrophs as suggested in my answer below

Comment: hmm. i've stopped using img tags. now i mostly use div's with background-image non repeating. Assign an listener for click. You can even swap out image for hover, or selected. Much cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @nix Sorry, in the real code it's a more complex expression. The tick marks are there in the live code.

Comment: @MilchePatern Both images display correctly when I go to them from the browser as website/images/btnRegister.png and website/images/btnUnregister.png

Comment: @dfsq It may have something to do with the fact that the the HTML is dynamically generated and inserted into a <div></div>.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to (missing apostrophs):

```
function register() {
    $('#reg').attr("src","/images/btnUnregister.png");              
    $('#reg').attr("onClick","unRegister()");          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ick, I hate inline JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click','#reg',function(e) {
//  e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr("src")==="/images/btnRegister.png") {
        $(this).attr("src","/images/btnUnregister.png");   
    } else {
        $(this).attr("src","/images/btnRegister.png");   
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: The javascript is generated dynamically at some point on the server so I decided not to bind to the click event since I don't want to deal with the housekeeping.

Comment: But that's the beauty of event delegation: by binding the event handler to `document` (ideally, it should be to the closest DOM parent), it's automatically applied to every child of `document` that matches the given selector. Simply use a useful class like `"reg"` and use `$(document).on('click','.reg',function(e) {...});` and you're set to go.

Comment: Good point. I'll incorporate it into the code.